# SynchronousQueue does not block when offered task by ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I use a pretty much default newCachedThreadPool but I want to limit the thread creation so I create ExecutorService like this

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2,
            60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<>());
```

After reading javadocs I expected it to work in way that when I submit Runnable, taskExecutor blocks when offering SynchronousQueue a new task, untill there is available thread to execute it and then a handoff occurs. Unfortunately after reaching the thread pool capacity and when all threads are busy, taskExecutor throws RejectedExecutionException. I know I can pass a RejectedExecutionHandler that will block, but I'm just suprise that it seems I have to. Can someone explain if it is really working as intended or am I doing something wrong?

This code reproduces my case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2,
            60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<>());

    while (true) {
        executor.submit(() -> System.out.println("bla"));
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you can attach code that reproduces your case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in accordance with ThreadPoolExecutor API:

• If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

As to why `SynchronousQueue` does not block - because `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses `queue.offer()` instead of `put()`

Comment: This behaviour can be quite confusing and it is not expressed in javadoc in any way.

Comment: @ŁukaszChorąży it does talk about the Direct handoffs that uses "...a SynchronousQueue that hands off tasks to threads without otherwise holding them" Which implies the task will be reject if there isn't a waiting, or available, thread.

Answer (score 0):

`SynchronousQueue` doesn't block until something takes the waiting element because `offer` is used. It just fails to add the element to the queue. The blocking queue part is the **take** method, which blocks until an element is added.

```
SynchronousQueue<Integer> que = new SynchronousQueue<>();

    System.out.println(que.offer(1));
    Object lock = new Object();
    synchronized(lock){
        new Thread(()->{ 
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.notify();
            }
            try{
                que.take();
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    ).start();
        lock.wait();
    }
    System.out.println(que.offer(1));
```

This example will output false, then *maybe* (slight race condition) true. The first add just fails because nobody is waiting to take the offered element.